# Make plot and trace same color by factor plotly R

Tags: r, plotly

I have a scatter plot with 3 factors.  I add 3 traces where each trace corresponds to a factor.  I want the scatter plot and the trace to be the same color.  Here is simple function to generate appropriate test data:

```
## generate test data
getTestData <- function(seed_val=711, noise=1.0) {
    set.seed(seed_val)
    d <- seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), as.Date('2017/01/08'), "days")
    first_name <- rep("Jane", 8)
    first_name <- append(first_name, rep("Fred", 8))
    first_name <- append(first_name, rep("Sally", 8))
    y1_vals <- seq(1, 3*8, 1)
    y2_vals <- rnorm(3*8, mean=y1_vals, sd=noise)
    dat <- data.frame(date=d, f_name=first_name, y1=y1_vals, y2=y2_vals,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    return(dat)
}
```

If I create a data frame and pass it to plot_ly like this:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
df <- getTestData()
p1 <- plot_ly(df, x=~date, y=~y1, color=~f_name,
          type = 'scatter', mode = "lines+markers") %>% 
      layout(yaxis = list(title = "some important y value")) %>% 
      add_trace(y=~y2, name='actual', showlegend=TRUE, 
          type='scatter', mode='lines',
          line=list(width = 2, dash = 'dash', color=~f_name))
```

I get this:

[image]

How do I get the colors of the scatter and the corresponding trace to be the same?

This wasn't quite what I needed:
[Grouped line plots in Plotly R: how to control line color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923581/grouped-line-plots-in-plotly-r-how-to-control-line-color)

This was very close:
[Same color assigned to same level of factor in R plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031596/same-color-assigned-to-same-level-of-factor-in-r-plotly?rq=1)
but the author of this answer points out exactly the problem I run into when I try various hacks when they state:

> Note that hav[ing] factor variables can mess this up due to the ordering that plotly uses (which I can't decipher sometimes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
pal <- c("red", "blue", "green")
p1 <- plot_ly(df, x=~date, y=~y1, color=~f_name, colors = pal,
              type = 'scatter', mode = "lines+markers") %>% 
    layout(yaxis = list(title = "some important y value")) %>% 
    add_trace(y=~y2, name='actual', showlegend=TRUE, 
              type='scatter', mode='lines',
              line=list(width = 2, dash = 'dash'), color=~f_name, colors = pal)
p1
```

[image]

Comment: Yes.  I had tried something almost exactly like this, except that I placed the last 2 args of the trace within the line list.  Thanks for clearing this up for me.